# Shedskin can't locate module numpy

Tags: python, c++, numpy, module, shedskin

I'm using shedksin to convert a python file (that is dependent on numpy) to a C++ file. When executing through command prompt I get the error. Any ideas on what might be the problem ?

Comment: Same problem, but with the `Tkinter` module

Comment: Pythran is another Python-to-C++ compiler for a subset of Python that includes partial `numpy` support (it acts a little like Numba and Cython—you annotate a function’s arguments, and then it takes over with further type annotation and code specialization).

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer. From Shedskin implementation:

## Library Limitations

Programs to be compiled with **Shed Skin** cannot freely use the Python standard library. Only about 17 common modules are currently supported.

Note that **Shed Skin** can be used to build an extension module, so the main program can use arbitrary modules (and of course all Python features!). See Compiling an Extension Module.

In general, programs can only import functionality that is defined in the **Shed Skin** lib/ directory. The following modules are largely supported at the moment:

- bisect
- collections
- ConfigParser
- copy
- datetime
- fnmatch
- getopt
- glob
- math
- os (some functionality missing under Windows)
- os.path
- random
- re
- socket
- string
- sys
- time